# When using scikit-learn K-Means Clustering, how can you extract the centroids in original data domain?

Tags: python, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using the `sklearn KMeans` k-means clustering algorithm. Before clustering, I normalize my data from `[0,1]` using

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

Now, I can run the K-means algorithm.

```
kmeans = KMeans(
        init="random",
        n_clusters=3,
        n_init=10,
        max_iter=3000,
    )
    kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
```

Then, I can extract the 3 cluster centroids using `kmeans.cluster_centers_`. However, these centroids are in the *normalized domain [0,1].* How can I re-transform these to the *original data domain?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the corrdinates in [0,1] scale , then use scaler.inverse_tranform to convert them to the original coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't realize `scaler` would remember the dataset in its `inverse_transform` method since the data I am transforming was generated, not pulled from that dataset.